# Manufactured planetoid

Tags: science-based, physics

Could a 'planetoid' created by reassembling pieces of a shattered planet, use the cooled metallic remains of a neutron star as its hub?

Comment: Have you got an idea of the tech level the civilisation who manufacture this would have?

Comment: @LioElbammalf It's necessary to consider the technological level, the question only asks if it could be done. The rest is mere engineering.

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! If you have a moment please [take the tour](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) and [visit the help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about the site (and earn a badge ;) ). Have fun!

Comment: Make bricks from the pieces of a planet and assembly the form you need. No need to wait for the thing to settle-down under the gravity which could take million years, even if that piece of NS could be possible(most likely, it is not)

Answer (score 4):

Not really.

The reason why is pretty simple: The material that makes up neutron stars is only as dense as it is because the gravity of the neutron star is pulling it all together. If you take some [degenerate matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_matter) (technical term meaning the atoms that make up the matter are overlapping) out of the star, then it's going to want to expand back out into regular old matter.

Which means that the hub of your planet has to be a whole neutron star in order to be made of neutron star material. At which point it isn't a planet anymore. It's a star.

If, however, you don't care whether or not it stays degenerate then why are you even bothering with the neutron star? Put a load of rocks in the same place, let gravity do it's work and then the planet will naturally force it's way into planet shape. You'll want to watch out for heat generated as everything settles into place (the [gravitational binding energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_binding_energy)), and any civilisation doing this kind of planetary engineering is going to have to have a serious amount of power available (probably nearing [Kardashev II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kardashev_scale#Type.C2.A0II_civilization_methods)) and some impressive engineering credentials.

If you absolutely want to tear matter out of a neutron star then everything gets much, *much* harder (Seriously. Even the tidal forces involved are mind boggling), and the net result is pretty much the same. So my advice is to forget about the star unless it's absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the neutron star remnant would be acting as a gravitational attractant to pull the fragments of the shattered planet together. In that sense, this process is feasible.

For clarification, in this case a neutron star remnant is not a full neutron satr, it is a piece of neutron star. using small fragments of a neutron star is more feasible route of building planetoids. Remembering a planetoid is only an astronomical object that is a dwarf planet like Ceres and below. Sometimes, actually quite often, they are called asteroids.

However, what may this infeasible is whether the neutron star remnant would be stable. If it's stable, then using the gravity of the neutron star remnant the shatter planet fragments could be pulled together to form a planetoid. Sorry about the repetition, but helps preserve the magic. of course, if the neutron star remnant isn't stable it may be emitting neutrons, gamma radiation and sundry other particles. Possibly not, surviving long enough to assemble a planetoid.

This is a big unknown in the picture. The stability of the neutron star remnant.

An actual neutron star, assuming its cooled and isn't rotating at high speed would have stellar mass, several times the mass of the Sun, in which this wouldn't form a planetoid at all. It would form a planetary matter coated neutron star, initially.  Gradually the ordinary planetary matter would be crushed into a thin layer and it turn it would become neutronic matter , part of the neutron star proper.

Of course, to do this, is a non-trivial engineering exercise and would require an extremely advanced technological civilization to do so. But this would be the least of the problems in making a planetoid using a neutron star (complete) or even a fragment of a neutron star (with its unknown stability problems).